# COleDispatchDriver with a specific exe as the COM server

Tags: com, mfc

I have inherited an application that consists of a bunch of exe files that communicate using COM and COleDispatchDriver. There is one main "client" exe, and several "server" executables that provide services.

At the moment, the client process starts the servers using COleDispatchDriver::CreateDispatch(), passing an application ID that gets resolved to a class ID. The problem with this is that it relies on the COM server being registered (a potential point of failure). It can also be problematic if there are several different versions of the COM server exes on the machine.

I'd like to make this less fragile without having to completely rearchitect the application at this point. Is there any way to keep the same mechanism for communication, but explicitly start a specific server application? The client knows where the server apps are and what they are called (they are alongside the client in the same directory).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more tricky but you can manually marshal the interfaces you need yourself. Get the client to fire the server up which creates the client object and marshalls an interface of it back to the client using `CoMarshallInterface()`.

Once the client has marshalled the interface you should be able to get hold of a IDispatch interface with simply a call to QueryInterface.